# Remote desktop Connectivity from windows 8 to Mac

Tags: windows, macos, windows-8, controls, remote-desktop

I have new Mac mini, and now my requirements is to connect my other friends pc Laptops(window 8) connected remotely with the mac, kindly guide me on the right direction for this approach achievement.

Answer (score 1):

In the Mac OS **System Preferences** in the Menu **Sharing** you have to activate **Screen Sharing**.

The in the Computer Settings you could optionally activate a VNC password. From windows you can use one of the free VNC Clients which are out there. 
([TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php), [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/) and many others)

Hope this helps...